# UIHostingController in share extension does not resize it's root view

Tags: ios, swift

I used swiftUI in share extension, using UIHostingController. When user changes device orientation when share extension is open, UIHostingController rootView does not change it's width

Answer (score 0):

So the actual problem was this function 
`func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }`

It caused the container it was applied to never change it's width and height, which caused the effect, consequently making the container look horrible when changing device orientation from portrait to landspace